# How to generate random numbers from the best fitted distribution with gamlss?

Tags: r, gamlss

### Objective

Find the best fitted distribution for data and then generate random numbers from this distribution.

### Example

Using the `gamlss` package in R, I found that the best fit distribution is `"Skew exponential power (Azzalini type 1)"`:

```
library(gamlss)
library(gamlss.dist)
library(gamlss.add)


m1 <- fitDist(mtcars$wt, k = 2, type = "realAll", trace = FALSE, try.gamlss = TRUE)

  
summary(m1)
# *******************************************************************
#   Family:  c("SEP1", "Skew exponential power (Azzalini type 1)") 
# 
# Call:  gamlssML(formula = y, family = DIST[i]) 
# 
# Fitting method: "nlminb" 
# 
# 
# Coefficient(s):
#   Estimate   Std. Error     t value Pr(>|t|)
# eta.mu     3.440000000  0.000149516 23007.56651  < 2e-16
# eta.sigma -1.856665040  0.861826733    -2.15434 0.031214
# eta.nu     0.150728244           NA          NA       NA
# eta.tau   -3.524272086           NA          NA       NA
# 
# eta.mu    ***
#   eta.sigma *  
#   eta.nu       
# eta.tau      
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  
#   0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Degrees of Freedom for the fit: 4 Residual Deg. of Freedom   28 
# Global Deviance:     -27.4747 
# AIC:     -19.4747 
# SBC:     -13.6117 
# Warning message:
#   In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced
```

#### Error

But the values of `sigma` and `tau` are negative. When I provide these values to `rSEP1()` to generate a random number, it throws the following error:

```
rSEP1(1, mu = 3.44, sigma = -1.8, nu = 0.15, tau = -3.5)
# Error in rSEP1(1, mu = 3.44, sigma = -1.8, nu = 0.15, tau = -3.5) : 
#   sigma must be positive
```

Are these values transformed? How can I provide correct inputs to `rSEP1()`?

Comment: If you run `gamlssML(mtcars$wt, family=SEP1)` you will get a warning about a convergence problem so maybe the coefficients are just meaningless.

Comment: @RobertHacken thanks for your comment. Could you please elaborate on why the coefficients *maybe* meaningless? Is there a way to find out if they are definitely meaningless? I see this warning: `possible convergence problem: optim gave code=1 false convergence`

Comment: It appears I was overly suspicious, thinking that the fitting algorithm, not converging properly, might have returned coefficients that were not valid for the given distribution. However, after reading Allan's nice answer I see that this is not the case and the coefficients are perfectly meaningful when transformed correctly (albeit not much reliable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the link functions for the parameters, you will see:

```r
SEP1()

#> GAMLSS Family: SEP1 Skew exponential power (Azzalini type 1) 
#> Link function for mu   : identity 
#> Link function for sigma: log 
#> Link function for nu   : identity 
#> Link function for tau  : log
```

So the values for sigma and tau that `fitDist` returns are the *log* of the numbers you would plug into `rSEP1`. In other words, the correct way to run `rSEP1` from your model is:

```r
rSEP1(1, mu = 3.44, sigma = exp(-1.8), nu = 0.15, tau = exp(-3.5))
#> [1] 3.460991
```

To show that this is the case, let us create a set of random numbers from a defined `rSEP1` where sigma = 0.5, and tau = 0.5. If we then find the best-fitting distribution, we should get results close to log(0.5) for both sigma and tau. Since `log(0.5)` is about -0.69, we would expect values of about -0.69 for both these parameters:

```r
set.seed(1)
testvec <- rSEP1(10000, mu = 3.5, sigma = 0.5, nu = 2.5, tau = 0.5)
m2 <- fitDist(testvec, k = 2, type = "realAll", trace = FALSE, try.gamlss = TRUE)

m2
#> Family:  c("SEP1", "Skew exponential power (Azzalini type 1)") 
#> Fitting method: "nlminb" 
#> 
#> Call:  gamlssML(formula = y, family = DIST[i]) 
#> 
#> Mu Coefficients:
#> [1]  3.5
#> Sigma Coefficients:
#> [1]  -0.6828
#> Nu Coefficients:
#> [1]  2.421
#> Tau Coefficients:
#> [1]  -0.6952
```

And plugging the exponents of sigma and tau into `dSEP1` gives us a near-perfect fit to the density of our test vector:

```r
d <- density(testvec)
plot(d$x, d$y)
lines(d$x, dSEP1(d$x, mu = 3.5, sigma = exp(-0.68), nu = 2.42, tau = exp(-0.69)),
     col = "red", lwd = 2, lty = 2)
```

[image]

It's worth pointing out that the actual fit obtained for `mtcars$wt` in the example is pretty terrible. The small value of sigma jyst means that most random values drawn from the distribution will be close to the mean of `mtcars$wt`. There are only 32 points in the data set, which makes it very difficult to automatically fit a parametric distribution accurately.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand this fitting process better now.